# Transactional Kafka Listener and Producer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am  new to spring and kafka . I have a use case to consume from a kafka topic and produce to  another topic using a transactional producer(messages should be processed only once) .I saw the discussion on this thread  (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/645) but  implemented it little differently .
I set a manual ack mode in the listener container factory  and then did an acknowledgent   after sending to producer using  kafkatemplate.executeinTransaction(aysnc send) .Does that acheive the same result as this one ? . Since the send is asynchnrous I am not sure it will serve the purpose

Also in the above example on issue 645  when does the actual commit to kafka broker happen ?(consumer see the data ). Does it happen  on a commit interval or record by record ?.I am trying to understand if the actual commit happens on a time interval/for every record or  is it  something configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using transactions you should not commit offsets via the consumer; instead, you should send the offsets to the transaction using the producer.

If properly configured, the listener container will do it automatically for you when the listener exits. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#transactions).

By configuring the listener container with a `KafkaTransactionManager`, the container starts the transaction. Any sends on a transactional `KafkaTemplate` will participate in the transaction and the container will send the offsets to the transaction (and commit the transaction) when the listener exits normally.

See the Javadocs for `executeInTransaction`...

```
/**
 * Execute some arbitrary operation(s) on the operations and return the result.
 * The operations are invoked within a local transaction and do not participate
 * in a global transaction (if present).
 * @param callback the callback.
 * @param <T> the result type.
 * @return the result.
 * @since 1.1
 */
<T> T executeInTransaction(OperationsCallback<K, V, T> callback);
```

Such operations **will not** participate in the container's transaction.

Comment: How can I participate Kafka template transaction with the global transaction?

Comment: Don't comment on an old answer with a new question. Instead, ask a completely new question and provide much more information about what you are trying to achieve. This question is too general for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to consumer offset commit there are two ways, one is enabling

```
enable.auto.commit is set to true
auto.commit.interval.ms      // configuring time for commit intervals
```

The other way is commit offset manually through Acknowledgement

```
@KafkaListener(topics="${kafka.consumer.topic}", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory", groupId="${kafka.consumer.groupId}")
public void taskListner(Task task, Acknowledgment Ack) {
    //System.out.println(task.toString());
    log.info(task.toString());
    Ack.acknowledge();              
}
```

The consumer auto check is called in every poll interval and checks time elapsed is greater than configured, if then it will commit the offset

Comment: If you are using transactions you should not commit offsets via the consumer; instead, you should send the offsets to the transaction using the producer. The listener container will do it automatically for you when the listener exits. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#transactions).

Comment: i know you will hail it because i saw you here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.html#setRecordFilterStrategy-org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordFilterStrategy-  in the Author

Comment: @GaryRussell Unfortunately the link is a 404.

Comment: New link is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions); but ignore the stuff about producer per consumer partition - that is obsolete in the current version - see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2515 (unless you are using an unsupported version with EOSMode.V1 (ALPHA)).